# Estructuras iguales (isomorfos) de dos arboles binarios en Python?

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos

estoy con un ejercicio en python donde pide averiguar si dos arboles binarios son isomorfos (estructuras iguales). La verdad que estoy confundido y no tengo idea como averiguar la estructura de cada árbol. Osea, cuantos nodos padres, cuantos hijos, etc, para realizar la comparación.
Muchas gracias!!

```
class Arbol:  
   def __init__(self, valor = None):
        if valor != None:
            self.valor = valor
        else: 
            self.valor = None
        self.derecho = None
        self.izquierdo = None
        
        
    def Agregar(self, carga):
        if self.valor:
            if carga < self.valor:
                if self.izquierdo is None:
                    self.izquierdo = Arbol(carga)
                else:
                    self.izquierdo.Agregar(carga)
                
            elif carga > self.valor:
                if self.derecho is None:
                    self.derecho = Arbol(carga)
                else:
                    self.derecho.Agregar(carga)        
        else:
            self.valor = carga
            
    
    def Imprimir(self):
        if self.izquierdo:
            self.izquierdo.Imprimir()
        
        print(self.valor)

        if self.derecho: 
            self.derecho.Imprimir()

arbol1 = Arbol(12)
for i in range(7):
    num = random.randint(0,25)
    print("numero: ",num)
    arbol1.Agregar(num)
print("Ascendente:")
arbol1.Imprimir()

arbol2 = Arbol('k')
lstAbecedario = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
for x in range(7):
    letra = lstAbecedario[random.randint(0,25)]
    print("letra: ", letra)
    arbol2.Agregar(letra)
print("Ascendente:")
arbol2.Imprimir()
```

arbol1 contiene numero cargados de manera aleatoria y arbol2 letras cargadas aleatoria de acuerdo a la lista lstAbecedario. Necesito saber si ambos tienen la misma estructura.

Comment: no podemos ayudarte si no muestras lo que has intentado

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias por responde. Ahí agregue el código, a ver si se entiende un poco mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Python tiene *métodos mágicos*. Cuando quieres ejecutar una acción con un objeto, Python busca métodos especiales (*mágicos*) en la definición de la clase.

Por ejemplo, cuando Python necesita la representación en caracteres de una objeto, internamente llama al método `__str__` del objeto.

Si lo deseas, puedes implementar estos métodos en tu clase, reemplazando la implementación por default de cada uno.

Si queremos comparar un objeto de clase `Arbol` con otro de igual clase y ver si son iguales, sólo necesitas agregar la función `__eq__(self, other)`, que será llamada cada vez comparemos un objeto `Arbol` contra cualquiera otra cosa.

Como se haga la comparación es cosa nuestra, y para estos propósito voy a definir que dos árboles son iguales si tienen la misma estructura (no mismo contenido necesariamente).

Mi comparación será recursiva. En cada invocación examinare:

1. Ambos derechos contienen algo o `None`.
2. Ambos izquierdos contienen algo o `None`.
3. Los sub-árboles derecho son iguales (vía llamada recursiva).
4. Los sub-árboles izquierdos son iguales (vía llamada recursiva).

Si falla cualquiera de estas condiciones, los árboles no tienen la misma estructura.

El nuevo método de la clase es:

```
def __eq__(self, other):        
    iguales = False
    if self.derecho:
        if other.derecho:
            if self.izquierdo:
                if other.izquierdo:
                    iguales = True
            elif not other.izquierdo:
                iguales = True
    elif not other.derecho:
        iguales = True

    if iguales:
        iguales = self.derecho == other.derecho and self.izquierdo == other.izquierdo

    return iguales
```

**Demo**

```
arbolA = Arbol(1)
arbolA.derecho = Arbol(2)
arbolA.izquierdo = Arbol(3)

arbolB = Arbol(4)
arbolB.derecho = Arbol(5)
arbolB.izquierdo = Arbol(6)

if arbolA == arbolB:
    print("1. iguales")
else:
    print("2. distintos")

arbolA.derecho.derecho = Arbol(7)

if arbolA == arbolB:
    print("3. iguales")
else:
    print("4. distintos")
```

produce:

```
1. iguales
4. distintos

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu repuesta! En realidad, como el ejercicio corresponde a un curso de aprendizaje, consiste en no aplicar ningún método especial. Me imagino que habrá que descifrar si son iguales o no por medio del recorrido. Investigue algo sobre el recorrido por niveles y guardar el contenido de los nodos en un vector, pero no lo tengo muy en claro. Abrazo!